# Calling saveAndFlush within a JPA Transaction

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have an application that persists data within a transaction using JPA 'save'.  A second application accesses this data asynchronously on receiving a message from the first application.  However, depending on timing the data is sometimes not accessible by the second application as the main transaction has not yet completed (or is delayed).  I am considering changing 'save' to 'saveAndFlush'.  Will this ensure that the objects are saved contemporaneously?  Will the objects persisted with 'saveAndFlush' be rolled back on a transaction failure?

Comment: That won't solve your problem. The data still won't be visible unless the transaction has committed. Flushing isn't committing and thus nothing outside the transaction can see the data. So no it will not solve your problem.

Comment: You will want to look into your transaction's lifecycle hooks, and use a postComplete callback to send your message so you can determine that it was successful and actually complete. Or use another layer to send the message after your transactional method returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects persisted with `saveAndFlush` will be rolled back but this will not solve your real problem as changes wont be visible to a request from the second application until the transaction is committed.